# How to check if a column A IN (3,4,5) and A NOT IN (1,2)

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables.

Visits (Parent)
VisitDocs (Child)

I need to show all the visits which has at least docType 3 and doesn't have DocType 1 and 2. There are different DocTypes 1 to 15.

Example:

[image]

Result should be 101 because visit 101 doesn't have docType 1 or 2. It is one to many relation.

I have tried the following query but it doesn't work.

```
Select v.visitID, d.visitdoc From Visits v

INNER JOIN VisitDocs d ON d.VisitID = v.VisitID

WHERE d.docType = 3 and d.docType Not IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Are those records comma separated?

Comment: I’m confused. You say docType 3 is valid, but then say that docType 1 and 3 are *not* valid. How is this possible?

Comment: I need to show all the visits which has docType 3 but doesn't have DocType 1 and 2.

Comment: i have updated my question so that it can be more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer above seems very close, just duplicated a similar structure and tested.  My revised select below (just removed the 'AS' keyword and changed the last 'NOT IN' to 'IN' and it seems to work for me.

```
SELECT v.visitID
FROM Visits v
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * 
   FROM VisitDocs d
   WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID
   AND d.docType = 3)
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM VisitDocs d
                  WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID
                  AND d.docType IN (1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I am sure you can do this via a couple JOINs (or at least part of it) but you did not request what your return columns should be

```
SELECT v.visitID
FROM Visits AS v
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * 
  FROM VisitDocs AS d
  WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID
    AND d.docType = 3)
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM VisitDocs AS d
                 WHERE d.VisitID = v.VisitID
                   AND d.docType Not IN (1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT visitID FROM Visits GROUP BY visitID
HAVING max(decode(docType, 3, 0)) = max(decode(docType, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Go in on the required condition, then for the negative cases use an outer join with the non-key condition in the join condition with a null result in the where clause to "match" on missing rows, then finally join into the main table and its children:

```
select v.*, vd.*
from VisitDocs vd3
left join VisitDocs vd2 on vd2.VisitId = vd3.VisitId
    and vd2.docType = 2
left join VisitDocs vd1 on vd1.VisitId = vd3.VisitId
    and vd1.docType = 1
join Visit v on v.id = vd3.VisitId
join VisitDocs vd.VisitId = vd3.VisitId
where vd3.docType = 3
and vd2.VisitId is null
and vd1.VisitId is null
```

If you have an index on `VisitDocs(docType)` and `VisitDocs(VisitId)` it should perform pretty well.